# How to graph vectors using tikz?

Tags: tikz-pgf

I have been using the tikz package to try to represent the sum of vectors in the plane (parallelogram method). However, I have failed in the attempt because I do not know how to modify the limits of the axes and that the advance is 5 units because I want to represent (5,0) + (45,15) but the graphic representation is excessively large

```
\documentclass{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}    

\begin{tikzpicture}
    %eje x
    \draw[ultra thick, ->](-0.5,0)--(6.5,0) node [right]{$x$};
    %eje y
    \draw[ultra thick, ->](0,-0.5)--(0,6.5) node [left]{$y$};
    \foreach \x in {5,10,15,20,25}
    \draw (\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1) node[below]{$\x$};
\end{tikzpicture}
    
\end{document}
```

[image: that's what i got]

Comment: Can you provide a minimal example we can use as a foundation to give you answers?

Comment: Maybe provide an example code (that can be compiled) and also an image of the expected outcome. Otherwise, it is a lot to guess.3

Comment: I already included the code. Thank you

Comment: As @Dr. Manuel Kuehner already mentioned. What should it look like in the end?

Answer (score 1):

Ok I am taking a guess what you want:

Parsing the values of the `\foreach` I basically used `\pgfmathparse{<expression>}` like described [here](https://tex.stackexchange.com/a/116689/224762).

```
\documentclass[border=1cm]{standalone}
\usepackage{tikz}


\begin{document}
    


\begin{tikzpicture}
    %eje x
    \draw[ultra thick, ->](-0.5,0)--(6,0) node [right]{$x$};
    %eje y
    \draw[ultra thick, ->](0,-0.5)--(0,6) node [left]{$y$};
    \foreach \x in {0.5,1,...,4.5,5}{
    \draw (\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1);
    \draw node at (\x, -10pt) {%
        \pgfmathparse{\x*10}
        \pgfmathprintnumber[
        ]{\pgfmathresult}%
    };}


    % parallelogram with vectors
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,label=left:A](A) at(2,2)  {};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,label=left:B](B) at(3,3)  {};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,label=right:C](C) at(4,3)  {};
    \node[inner sep=0pt,outer sep=0pt,label=right:D](D) at(3,2)  {};
        
    \draw [-latex] (A) edge (B) (B) edge (C) (D) edge (A) (C) edge (D);
\end{tikzpicture}
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

You could also try to modify either `scale=` or the default tikz-length with the options `x=` and `y=`.

Here is some example code doing both of this:

```
\documentclass[tikz]{standalone}
\begin{document}    
    \begin{tikzpicture}[scale=.1,vector/.style={->,>=stealth,thick},unitvector/.style={ultra thick, ->,>=stealth,gray}]

        \draw[unitvector](-0.5,0)--(6.5,0) node [right]{$x$};
        \draw[unitvector](0,-0.5)--(0,6.5) node [left]{$y$};
        \foreach \x in {5,10,...,50}{
            \draw (\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1) node[anchor=north,font=\footnotesize]{$\x$};
        }
        \draw[vector] (0,0) -- (0,5);
        \draw[vector] (0,5) -- ++(45,15);
    \end{tikzpicture}

    \begin{tikzpicture}[x=.1cm,y=.1cm,vector/.style={->,>=stealth,thick},unitvector/.style={ultra thick, ->,>=stealth,gray}]
        \draw[unitvector](-0.5,0)--(6.5,0) node [right]{$x$};
        \draw[unitvector](0,-0.5)--(0,6.5) node [left]{$y$};
        \foreach \x in {5,10,...,50}{
            \draw (\x,0.1)--(\x,-0.1) node[anchor=north,font=\footnotesize]{$\x$};
        }
        \draw[vector] (0,0) -- (0,5);
        \draw[vector] (0,5) -- ++(45,15);
    \end{tikzpicture}
\end{document}
```

Both result in the same image:

[image]